# How do i migrate a oracle sql tables to mongodb?

Tags: mysql, oracle, mongodb

i have created a few tables which have related table using Oracle SQL. My lecturer want me to migrate these into a mongodb , i have searched on web but i am clueless on what they are doing . i know how to setup mongodb and get connection but i dont know how to migrate to mongodb.

This is my tables i have created

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_EVENT_ORDER
 (
  ORDER_ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_TBL_EVENT_ORDER     
  PRIMARY KEY,
  CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENT FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_ID) REFERENCES
  TBL_CLIENT(CLIENT_ID),
  ORDER_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  EVENT_ID INT DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT FK_WINE_EVENT FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID) REFERENCES
  TBL_WINE_EVENT(EVENT_ID)
 );

CREATE INDEX IDX_FK_CLIENT_ID_TBL_CLIENT ON TBL_EVENT_ORDER(CLIENT_ID);
INSERT INTO TBL_EVENT_ORDER VALUES
(1,'1',DEFAULT,'1');
INSERT INTO TBL_EVENT_ORDER VALUES
(2,'2',DEFAULT,'1');
INSERT INTO TBL_EVENT_ORDER VALUES
(3,'3',DEFAULT,'1');
INSERT INTO TBL_EVENT_ORDER VALUES
(4,'4',DEFAULT,'1');


CREATE TABLE TBL_WINE
 (
   WINE_ID INT CONSTRAINT PK_WINE PRIMARY KEY,
   WINE_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
   PRICE NUMBER(6,2) CONSTRAINT NN_PRICE NOT NULL,
   WINE_TYPE VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT NN_WINE_TYPE NOT NULL,
   WINE_YEAR INT CONSTRAINT NN_WINE_AGE NOT NULL,
   WINE_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(20),
   WINE_REGION VARCHAR2(20)
 );

INSERT INTO TBL_WINE VALUES
(1,'AGUILA RED',100.50,'BORDEAUX',2010,'COUNTRY1','REGION1');
INSERT INTO TBL_WINE VALUES
(2,'CLOUD BAY',150,'BORDEAUX',2010,'COUNTRY2','REGION2');
INSERT INTO TBL_WINE VALUES
(3,'HARLAN ESTATE',175.50,'BORDEAUX',2010,'COUNTRY3','REGION3');
INSERT INTO TBL_WINE VALUES
(4,'KRUG',200,'BORDEAUX',2010,'COUNTRY4','REGION4');

CREATE TABLE TBL_ORDER_DETAIL
 (
  ORDER_ID INT,
  WINE_ID INT,
  CONSTRAINT PK_ORDER_DETAIL PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID, WINE_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_EVENT_ORDER FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES      
  TBL_EVENT_ORDER(ORDER_ID),
  ORDER_QTY INT CONSTRAINT NN_ORDER_QTY NOT NULL,
  UNIT_PRICE NUMBER(6,2),
  EXCLUSIVE_IMPORT CHAR(1)
);

CREATE INDEX IDX_FK_ORDER_ID_EVENT_ORDER ON TBL_ORDER_DETAIL(ORDER_ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_FK_WINE_ID_WINE ON TBL_ORDER_DETAIL(WINE_ID);

INSERT INTO TBL_ORDER_DETAIL VALUES
(1,1,3,100.50,'N');
INSERT INTO TBL_ORDER_DETAIL VALUES
(2,2,1,150,'N');
INSERT INTO TBL_ORDER_DETAIL VALUES
(3,3,4,175.50,'N');
INSERT INTO TBL_ORDER_DETAIL VALUES
(4,4,2,200,'Y');
```

Comment: This is nonsensical - Mongo has no schema.

Comment: See [How do I migrate data from a SQL Server DB to MongoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161928/how-do-i-migrate-data-from-a-sql-server-db-to-mongodb) It's closed as "too broad" and so is this. The whole point of using MongoDB as opposed to Oracle or MySQL is that you intend to store your data differently, Anyone who tells you otherwise does not know what they are talking about. I suspect your lecturer may be being clever and is actually trying to get you to "think about this very point". Being "how to change the design for MongoDB".

Comment: these are the question that my lecturer gave me. " Select a transaction of your choice involving at least 2 tables  and implement this set of 2 or more related tables into ONE collection in MongoDB.   "

Comment: what am i supposed to do?

Comment: Surely the questions are to designed to use the knowledge your lecturer has given in previous lectures. Did a lecture explain the concept of a collection in MongoDB?